# Keydown doesn't properly refresh ng-model in input text but keyup does

Tags: angularjs, keydown

I need to retrieve in a directive the value of a text input using ng-model to send value to a data base.
If I use in my directive the keydown event, and wrote for exemple 1234 in my input, the result show in my directive is 123, if I wrote abc, the result is ab.
If I use keyup, this problem doesn't exist (tested with firefox and chrome).
Why does it occur?

My code:

```
.directive('updateDbb', ["$http", function ($http) {
 return {
 restrict: 'A',
 require: 'ngModel',
  link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        // Listen for change events to enable binding
        var ngModelValue, inputName, testValid, dbbFieldName, idDbb;
        element.bind('keydown', function () {
            ngModelValue = ngModel.$viewValue;
            console.log(ngModelValue); // Show with delay, not the case with "keyup"!!!
```

...

Comment: That is exactly what you would expect. `keydown` is the first part of a `keypress` event. `keydown` is when the typing of the character is complete, and the value is then bound.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`keydown` fires when the user presses on a key, and **before** the character is being **inserted** into the input. **That's why it doesn't get updated**.

`keypress` fires when an actual character is being inserted in your input. I think it is the event you want to use (if the user maintains the key down, the event will be triggered once for per character inserted)

`keyup` fires when the user releases a key, after the character has been inserted into the input. (if the user maintains the key down, the event will only be triggered once)